# Tokenizing emojis contiguous to words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to tokenize strings that have the two following patterns:

- contiguous emojis, for instance "Hey, "
- emojis contiguous to words, for instance "surprise !!"

To do this, I have tried the `word_tokenize()` function from `nltk` ([doc](https://kite.com/python/docs/nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize)). However, it does not split the contiguous entities when emojis are involved.

For instance,

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
word_tokenize("Hey, ")
```

output: `['Hey', ',', '']`

I'd like to get: `['Hey', ',', '', '']`

and

```
word_tokenize("surprise !!")
```

output: `['surprise', '!', '!']`

I'd like to get `['surprise', '', '!', '!']`

Therefore, I was thinking maybe using specific regex pattern could solve the issue but I don't know what pattern to use.

Comment: What is your technical definition of an emoji?

Comment: Maybe this http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html ? But you need a function to test if a character belongs to this list.

Comment: Yes! I am only talking about those unicode emojis

Comment: Food for though: Does contiguous emoji mean different thing from each of them individually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `TweetTokenizer`

```
from nltk.tokenize.casual import TweetTokenizer
t = TweetTokenizer()
>>> t.tokenize("Hey, ")
['Hey', ',', '', '']
```

Answer (score 4):

Another better option is to use [SpaCyMoji](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacymoji) because NLTK Tweet Tokenizer fails to handle skin tone emojis.

```
from spacymoji import Emoji
nlp_spacymoji = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
emoji = Emoji(nlp_spacymoji, merge_spans=True)
nlp_spacymoji.add_pipe(emoji, first=True)
doc = nlp_spacymoji("One , skintone ✌, cluster , word & emo together")
print([token.text for token in doc])

# expected output
['One', '', ',', 'skintone', '✌', ',', 'cluster', '', '', ',', 'word', '&', 'emo', '', 'together']
```

For the same input, NLTK Tweet Tokenizer will produce

```
['One', '', ',', 'skintone', '✌', '', ',', 'cluster', '', '', ',', 'word', '&', 'emo', '', 'together']
```